# Как оптимизировать проект в Unreal Engine?

Tags: разработка-игр, unreal-engine-4

Сделал тестовый проект, сделал билд. При запуске сборки видеокарта нагружается на 90 процентов. Как можно оптимизировать?
Проверил на нескольких ПК.
На ноутбуках и ПК со слабой видеопамятью по 10 фпс выдает.
На ПК с rx 580 8gb и gtx 1660 загружает видеокарту на 90 - 100 процентов

Проект на BP. Без C++.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Возможно в каких-то моментах Вам стоит оптимизировать код, но на мой взгляд, вам нужно сделать настройки графики, ведь это Вам не Unity3D, где по умолчанию стоит графика на 2+. По умолчанию вы можете в настройках проекта [изменить графику](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vD5TTw8Xuo8) или же [оптимизировать её](https://pikabu.ru/story/povyishenie_proizvoditelnosti_proekta_na_unreal_engine_4_7300785?ysclid=l34inrtr67)

Comment: Спасибо огромное!

Comment: После того как поставил Forward Shading true проект не запускается, есть варианты решений?

Comment: А без него работает? посмотрите [оф.документацию](https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.27/en-US/TestingAndOptimization/PerformanceAndProfiling/ForwardRenderer/), у вас наподобие сделано?

Comment: Без него работает, а как его можно отключить если проект не запускается. На этапе Compilling shders крашится. Вот ошибка:

LoginId:fc446c4f4607c46a5994949b0a0a42dd
EpicAccountId:fd03fbfd6f5443248406c22a95504fb9

Fatal error: [File:D:\build\++UE5\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\Engine\Private\ShaderCompiler\ShaderCompiler.cpp] [Line: 7339] Failed to compile global shader FDistanceFieldShadowingCS . Enable 'r.ShaderDevelopmentMode' in ConsoleVariables.ini for retries.

Comment: В Unreal мало чего понимаю. Попробуйте выполнить рекомендацию - `Enable 'r.ShaderDevelopmentMode' in ConsoleVariables.ini for retries.`